# How do I eliminate the extra title bar?

Tags: compiz, unity-2d, window-manager, ccsm

I'm using Oneiric 11.10, Unity 2D, and compiz (modifying some ccsm settings); I've activated the effects plug-in on ccsm, and when I apply the changes by typing in the terminal `compiz --replace`, I get two title bars in a maximized window rather than only one, the first: the one which is integrated with the unity bar, and the other: the one of the window.

Here are some pictures:

- [DoubleTitleBar](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/4LlTa3Gzgxq6oFZ9hcuFLVM1iT1bUXa2qk0FS5tHPhg?feat=directlink): [image: img]
- [HowItShouldBe](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/rdIlPxShJU5SmZa7CakN6FM1iT1bUXa2qk0FS5tHPhg?feat=directlink): [image: img]

Comment: Did you uninstall the `unity` package? Someone else in a [recently-closed question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71090/unity-2d-double-titlebar-for-maximized-windows) had a similar problem caused by that.

Comment: Remarkably - I think this has just been answered... http://askubuntu.com/questions/71369/compiz-issues-in-unity-2d

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve the window decorator issue, simply run the following in the terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and the window decoration will immediately disappear:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string '/apps/compiz-1/plugins/decor/screen0/options/decoration_match' '!state=maxvert'
```

Or just as @joschi's answer suggest, you can do that graphically using the CCSM:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have set myself the 'decorations for windows' box to
    `!(state=maxvert & state=maxhorz)`
because I do want the decorations when the window is only vertically/horizontally maximized (by clicking the maximize button with the middle/right button, respectively), and I do not want them if it is fully maximized.

Comment: *Excellent*! No one seems to be mentioning `state=maxhorz`, but that is important, especially if you want to use the Window Grid plugin. I tried `maxhori` and `maxhoriz` and neither worked; should have figured this out. Took some searching. +1 upvote this answer people.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to change the settings in the 'Window decorations' option in CCSM. Type `!state=maxvert` in the 'decorations for windows' box which should remove the decorations of all maximized windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change settings only for specific application say firefox

```
!(class=Firefox & state=maxvert & state=maxhorz)
```

[Source](http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching)