# Using Compiz by default in Unity 2D

Tags: compiz, unity-2d

My hardware can handle Compiz fine, but not Unity 3D, annoyingly enough. I hate Metacity more than Unity 2D, so I switched compositors using `compiz --replace`. However that leaves me with two problems:

1. `compiz --replace` is temporary, it will revert back to Metacity, by the next reboot/login
2. Compiz leaves window decorator when the windows are maximized.

Comment: ... I think this is the same question... the bounty could be yours!  http://askubuntu.com/questions/70408/how-do-i-eliminate-the-extra-title-bar

Comment: @fossfreedom Answered with the window decorator part there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Compiz as default Unity 2D compositor**

Go to a Terminal and enter:

```
sudoedit /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu-2d.session
```

In the fifth line, change `metacity` to `compiz`:

```
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=compiz
```

**Remove window decoration from maximized windows**

To solve the window decorator issue, simply run the following in the terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and the window decoration will immediately disappear:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string '/apps/compiz-1/plugins/decor/screen0/options/decoration_match' '!state=maxvert'
```

The same can be done using the CompizConfig Settings Manager, CCSM, if you've installed it already:

[image]

Comment: Other places have suggested to use `!(state=maxvert & state=maxhorz)` instead, since that will activate it only for fully maximized windows, instead of partially ones