# Edge reveal timeout for Unity 2D

Tags: unity-2d, timeout

I am using Unity 2D, and I want to change the *Edge Reveal Timeout* for Unity 2D launcher. but `compiz-setting-manager` is not working for it. I think 2D and 3D don't share common settings.

So, how can I change *edge reveal timeout* for Unity 2D (currently its too slow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiz-Config Settings Manager isn't working for Unity 2D because Unity 2D uses Metacity instead of Compiz. You can enable Compiz on Unity 2D using the command `compiz --replace` in a terminal. After that, you can edit the reveal timeout settings in Compiz Config Settings Manager. However, this will be undone at the next startup. To get Compiz started up by default instead of Metacity in Unity 2D, use [this answer and question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71369/using-compiz-by-default-in-unity-2d).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are able to do that in Unity 2d, but this program might help:

http://m.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/unity-2d-tweak-app-updated-for-11-10/?wpmp_switcher=mobile

Comment: nop i have it already and it is useless in this case