# Can we use the window snap feature to fit a window to half the screen in Unity 2D?

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Aero Snap in Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41566/how-do-i-get-aero-snap-in-unity-2d)

In Unity 3D you can move a window to the left and right edge of the screen to fit it to half the screen. I'm sure I saw this work on Unity 2D on a fresh install on a friend's computer without any tweaking. But on my Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity 2D it doesn't.

Is this normal or am I missing something? I'm fairly sure it worked on Unity 2D on a friend's comp with no modifications.

Unless I'm somehow running on a non-default window manager? I'm on the latest Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit Desktop, fully updated. I'm not sure which window manager is supposed to be default for Unity 2D and whether that makes a difference to the snap feature?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a Compiz feature (Snapping windows), so unless you can run Compiz on your system, I'd say no.  I believe it **is** possible, although I haven't tried it.  I just Googled "unity 2D with compiz" and it seems that it's something people do.

Edit:
Forgot to add... this looks like a good set of instructions:
[askubuntu topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71369/using-compiz-by-default-in-unity-2d)