# How to run Compiz on Unity 2D, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: compiz, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Compiz by default in Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71369/using-compiz-by-default-in-unity-2d)

When I try to run compiz on Unity 2D I can't use de Dash, and all my workspaces reduces to one single workspace. I want to know how to enable compiz effects on Unity 2D without thouse problems.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because 2D is using Metacity. Simple fix though...

Open Unity 2D's session settings:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu-2d.session
```

Change metacity

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Ubuntu 2D
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;panel;launcher;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=metacity
DefaultProvider-panel=unity-2d-panel
DefaultProvider-launcher=unity-2d-launcher

DesktopName=Unity
```

To compiz

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Ubuntu 2D
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;panel;launcher;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=compiz
DefaultProvider-panel=unity-2d-panel
DefaultProvider-launcher=unity-2d-launcher

DesktopName=Unity
```

Save file and exit gedit

While still in terminal:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Log back in and have fun. Hope this helps :)